# SQL INSERTING DATA USING TRIGGERS

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a trigger that inserts sequences of type varchar into product_id for my product table. I also have an ordered_product table which looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERED_PRODUCT (
                order_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
                product_ID VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
                ordered_productQuantity NUMBER NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT ORDERED_PRODUCT_PK PRIMARY KEY (order_ID, product_ID)
);
```

This table links my product and orders table together.
I should use a trigger to insert the product_id from the product table into the ordered_product table. I have created a trigger that looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER orderedProductID_TRIG
AFTER INSERT ON product
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
v_productID PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID%TYPE;
BEGIN
     insert into ordered_product (product_id)
     values (:new.product_id);
END;
```

but when i try to insert data into my ordered_product table it shows an error:
cannot insert NULL into ("ORDERED_PRODUCT"."PRODUCT_ID")

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS that you are using. This looks like Oracle to me.

Comment: This makes no sense. When you add a product to your product list (`product` table)... you aren't ordering it are you? Why would you automatically create a record in `ordered_product`?  As an example: when you insert a record into `ordered_product` in your trigger, you aren't specifying a value for `ordered_productQuantity` (hence the null error). So the question is: how many are you ordering? 0? 1? 1000? You don't know because you aren't ordering anything, you are just creating a product master record

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid 's comment is spot-on.  It makes no sense to create an order when creating a product.  Unless you have an very unusual use-case, the existence of a product, does not mean that an order should exist for it (unless for example yo only make unique products to order).  Not only that, the odered_product entity needs an order_id and quantity too, so your insert in the trigger won't work with the object as defined.

Comment: The product table will store the products in stock and the orders table will store the orders made by the customers, this is why we need to keep track of the ordered products.

Comment: @M.Eb Following the line of questioning.  Just because you've added a product does not mean you also have an order.  Your trigger will never work because you are not providing the not null columns into your insert in order_product, namely because you do not have them.  Your order is a separate business entity that is inserted based on the order and references the product via product_id.  It is not something that exists when a product is created.